# I wanna put data to upper1000 of Price model

Tags: python, django

I wanna put data to upper1000 of Price model.
So I think I have to read upper1000 of Price,so I wrote

```
area = Area.objects.filter(name="America").first()
pref = Prefecture.objects.create(name="pref", area=area)
city = City.objects.create(name="city", prefecture=pref)
price = Price.objects.create(city=city)
price_u1000 = price.upper1000.create(city=city)
```

but AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create' error happens.
models.py is

```
class Price(models.Model):
    upper1000 = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='1000', null=True)
    from500to1000 = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='500～1000', null=True)
```

Why does this error happen?What is wrong?How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you initialize `Price.objects`?

Comment: @macmoonshine I updated my question.pref&city&price has Foreign keys,so I think if I initialize area,price also is initialized

Comment: @user8563636 No, Foreign key is not initializing other field

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, you can't use this `Price.objects.create(city=city)`
  because you haven't field `city` in your model. Need to use `Price.objects.create(upper1000=city.name)`
- Next, `upper1000` is `None` because as a result of your previous
  command, `upper1000` took `NULL`
- Final, for change variable `upper1000` use this:

  ```
  price.upper1000 = city.name
  price.save()
  ```

Comment: thx ur answer.I cannot understand from Final, for change variable~.Where is from city_name?Could u write in ur answer whole codes?

Comment: I read in your comment, that models have `Foreign key` can you update the question with is?